# Find $f_{X|Y=y}$ and $f_{Y|X=x}$ when $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=C\cdot \text{exp}\{-(1+x^{2})(1+y^{2})\}$

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, density-function

Consider the density

$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=C\cdot e^{-(1+x^{2})(1+y^{2})},\quad -\infty <x,y<\infty$

$C$ is a normalizing constant.

What are the conditional densities $f_{X|Y=y}(x)$ and $f_{Y|X=x}(y)$?

This is what I did:

$f_{X}(x)=C\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(1+x^{2})(1+y^{2})}\, dy$

$(1+x^{2})=b$

$I^{2}=\Big(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-b(1+y^{2})}\,dy\Big)\Big(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-b(1+w^{2})}\,dw\Big)\\
        =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Big(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-b(2+y^{2}+w^{2})}\, dy\Big)\, dw$

$y^{2}+w^{2}=r^{2},\quad dy\, dw=\, dA=r\, dr\, d\theta$

$I^{2}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\Big(\int_{0}^{\infty}re^{-b(2+r^{2})}\, dr\Big)\, d\theta\\
        =2\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}re^{-b(2+r^{2})}\, dr$

$u=b(2+r^{2})=2b+br^{2},\quad du=2br$

$2b\cdot I^{2}=2\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}2bre^{-b(2+r^{2})}\, dr\\
        =2\pi\int_{2b}^{\infty}e^{-u}\, du\\
        =2\pi\Big[-e^{-u}\Big]_{2b}^{\infty}\\
        =2\pi\Big(0+e^{-2b}\Big)=2\pi e^{-2b}$

$I=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{b}e^{-2b}}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{b}}e^{-b}$

$f_{X}(x)= C\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{(1+x^{2})}}e^{-(1+x^{2})}$

$f_{Y|X=x}(y)= \frac{C\cdot e^{-(1+x^{2})(1+y^{2})}}{C\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{(1+x^{2})}}e^{-(1+x^{2})}}\\
        = \sqrt{\frac{(1+x^{2})}{\pi}}e^{-(1+x^{2})(1+y^{2})+(1+x^{2})}\\
        =\sqrt{\frac{(1+x^{2})}{\pi}}e^{-(1+x^{2})y^{2}}$

$Y|X\in N(0,\frac{1}{2(1+x^{2})})$

$X|Y\in N(0,\frac{1}{2(1+y^{2})})$

Is this correct or have I missed something?

Comment: Looks okay. Also answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/184414/119261.